# The Yellow Problem

Tags: riddle, rhyme

This should be easy...

> A stirring that comes from within,
>   You fight me yet you never win,
>   A river helps to test your will,
>   The busy fight me harder still,

What am I?

Comment: Please change the title as it gives it away

Comment: For a moment I accidentally misread "Problem" as "Peril" and remembered a certain politically incorrect Monty Python sketch.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Sorry for this but in my view it fits perfectly.
Answer:

> pee/peeing

The Yellow Problem

> Yep, it's yellow-ish. Unless you have medical problems.

A stirring that comes from within,

> It comes from withing. Kidneys, bladder, ...

You fight me yet you never win,

> Just try not to do it. See how long you can last.

A river helps to test your will,

> hearing running water make is even harder to hold it in.

The busy fight me harder still,

> try not to go to the bathroom when you're busy. You cannot concentrate on what you are doing.

Comment: Yep.  That's it.  +1